# Meteor publishing information from server changes DOM and removes keyboard focus on the element

Tags: javascript, dom, meteor

I am trying to build an app like Google Docs that contains webpage with a textarea and on changing of the value I publish and update to the server and get back the response of the save from the server which updates the DOM.

The issue is that the updating of the DOM which happens later removes the textarea focus which user needs to keep typing. The focus is lost and the user has to click on the textarea again to gain focus and keep typing.

How can I overcome this issue of losing focus when a value is changed remotely on the server and sent to the client.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a session variable and the [rendered](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_rendered) callback on your template to do this. Here is a really simple example using a template with one textarea:

```html
<template name="home">
  <textarea></textarea>
</template>
```

```js
Template.home.events({
  'focus textarea': function() {
    Session.set('hasFocus', true);
  },
  'blur textarea': function() {
    Session.set('hasFocus', false);
  }
});

Template.home.rendered = function() {
  if (Session.get('hasFocus')) {
    $('textarea').focus();
  }
};

Template.home.destroyed = function() {
  return Session.set('hasFocus', undefined);
};
```

When you focus or blur the textarea, we modify the session variable `hasFocus`. Whenever the template is rendered we just focus the textarea based on the same variable. When we are done with the template, just clean up `hasFocus` so it doesn't interfere with other pages.

Comment: Hi David, this is assuming the caret is always at the end of whatever text present in the textarea. What if, say, the user has moved the caret back a couple of words, lines etc, then this refocusing will move his caret to the end. Can you think of a solution to this?

Comment: Yeah that's a good point. :) The only way I can think of to deal with that case is to not allow the textarea to be removed from the DOM in the first place (put it in a constant region). Unfortunately that eliminates any chance of a meteor binding - so you'd have to do all the bindings (update/initialize) in the `rendered` callback. This may be better with the new rendering engine coming out in 0.8 though.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried wrapping the element in {{#constant}} {{/constant}} tags?